# Earth Imaginary line , its application

Tags: globe

In asked question I have attached image which is some separator line on globe.

I  googled/stackoveflowed but did not find answer for following questions (for kid's home work).

1. What is the name of that line?
2. What is the significance of that line?
3. Why line shaped like hook? History behind it if any, any special consideration for shape of line.

[image]

Comment: It's the international date line: [https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dateline.html](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dateline.html)

Answer (score 1):

That line is called International Date Line.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line):

> The IDL is roughly based on the meridian of 180° longitude, roughly
>   down the middle of the Pacific Ocean, and halfway around the world
>   from the Greenwich meridian. In many places, the IDL follows the 180°
>   meridian exactly. In other places, however, the IDL deviates east or
>   west away from that meridian. These various deviations generally
>   accommodate the political and/or economic affiliations of the affected
>   areas.

Interesting fact of life is these deviations are not set and follow geopolitical situations.

For that specific patch, it is to accommodate the local needs of Kiribati / Line islands.

(more information on the above line, don't forget to read the references at the bottom of the article for more extended info)

It is literally 'All around Monday, and here Sunday' there. :)